# Контроль окончания видео в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

новичок в программировании, пытаюсь сделать интро (видео) в игре и после окончания этого видео должно совершиться определенное действие (а именно переход на другую сцену). Пыталась осуществить с помощью количества кадров в видео, но не получилось. Использовала VideoPlayer. В официальной документации похожего функционала не нашла. Помогите, пожалуйста(

код неудачной попытки

```
public void AutoLoadOurMenu()
{ 
    ulong numberFramesInVideo; //количество кадров в видео
    numberFramesInVideo = videoPlayer.frameCount; 
    ulong numberOfCurrentFrame; //номер текущего кадра 
    numberOfCurrentFrame = (ulong) videoPlayer.frame; 
    if (numberOfCurrentFrame== numberFramesInVideo) //ещё не совсем поняла, с 0 
    //или 1 идет отсчет кадров, но так: if (numberOfCurrentFrame== 
   // numberFramesInVideo-1) тоже пробовала, тоже неудачно
    {
     Application.LoadLevel(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

`VideoPlayer` содержит в себе событие `loopPointReached`, которое вызывается, когда VideoPlayer достигает конца видео. Чтобы оно сработало, в VideoPlayer должно быть включено зацикливание (*loop*). Чтобы вызвать какую-то функцию по окончанию видео, необходимо эту функцию на это событие подписать:

```cs
void OnEnable() //Сначала подписываем нашу функцию на событие конца видео
{
    videoPlayer.loopPointReached += OnVideoEnd;
}

void OnDisable() //Отписываем для предотвращения утечки памяти
{
    videoPlayer.loopPointReached -= OnVideoEnd;
}

void OnVideoEnd(UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer causedVideoPlayer)
{
    //Нужный вам код, который будет выполняться, когда видео закончится
}
```

Ссылки:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-know-video-player-is-finished-playing-video.483935/
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-loopPointReached.html

Comment: А если видео сбить?) Уровень никогда не загрузится.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы хотите таким же способом, то Вам нужно было изменить лишь несколько моментов:

```
ulong numberFramesInVideo; //количество кадров в видео (где ulong заранее объявлен)

private void Start(){ 
  numberFramesInVideo = videoPlayer.frameCount; 
}

public void Update()
{    
    if (videoPlayer.frame >= numberFramesInVideo)Application.LoadLevel(1);
}
```

Comment: А если сбить видео "videoPlayer.frame = numberFramesInVideo;" то можно пропустить вступную заставку